# Does Testflight only apps need to be updated to support iOS 13 SDK by April 2020?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13

According to Apple News **Starting April 2020, all new apps and app updates will need to be built with the iOS 13 SDK and support the all-screen design of iPhone XS Max or later.**
I have an app that runs on Xcode 10 and Swift 4, but it is not live on the App Store yet and is just available on Testflight.

> My doubt is whether I need to update to iOS 13 even if I just upload
>   the app to Testflight and not make it live on the Store?

Comment: Based on past experience your build will be rejected once you upload it, regardless of whether you intend to release that build or just test it